# modifying jhipster entity manually

Tags: mysql, maven, jhipster

**I just follow the steps given below**

- Run yo jhipster:entity entityName.
- Modify entities (add, remove, ...), at the end, jhipster will give question to override file, IMPORTANT NOTE: choose NO for changelog .xml file and navbar.html file.
- Back to project and run mvn compile liquibase:diff.
- 5. Run your application.
- No errors or warnings on this command (mvn compile liquibase:diff).

**The jhipster webapp changed. New Column updated.But No changes reflected in MYSQL-database**

On Running Maven project it shows the error(mvnw)
[jhipster_mysql_database_error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqcgb.png)

Answer (score 0):

`liquibase:diff` is only working, when you are changing your database manually, and want to have a difference between the migrated and your modified state. Changing just the entity classes and running liquibase:diff afterwards won't change anything.

In your scenario you should change your mysql database manually, and run liquibase:diff to make your changes taking effect

Comment: Yes , But if i use jdl file(*.jh) to update the entity , it reflects the database which means , it truncate all the existing data from the table. and update the columns.

Comment: import-jdl is more supposed to scaffold you to initialize your domain, rather then supporting accurate migration afterwards. I am currently working on a better migration support, but in production, you should me aware of your migrations by your self. Automatic generation often makes more bad then good at this point